# How to properly call Inject block or protocol api?

Tags: protocol, operation, blockchain, block, inject

I have question how to call properly inject block and inject protocol api methods which I have found here?

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/rpc-openapi.json

I was searching but I did not found any relevant documentation how to create data which I will fill into the API. Is there any guide how to create following input for the inject block methods?

```
curl --location 'https://02-dallas-051-01.rpc.tatum.io/injection/block' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxx' \
--data '{
  "data": "oorMJvcNv9338GGKGLTsM5EhCr96VuiLbE3yLLhT3myKa82QVdt",
  "operations": [
    [
      {
        "branch": "BMPvGANiByxUeTkMJM1LtkEUNapeMcTjxuEAr9crBZdaYwbQX6a",
        "data": "ddb22ca775467f08ba3288d53a141907d2f26c475f29e06032450749d50f35c86b00452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0f602adcdaf0acc0800007ff2737a3f5ed94332c4c44502133487ffcf6b27c1649713adff55345988a7486c00452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0f802aecdaf0ac90100c0843d0000452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0000c0e091e8d9c8bf0a3747538a03c0b1da5d77d19f7b14ffb6b7a000bf5c368f03c14f5259b4375def0bd5450e55ddbabdca9f645411dbd7dda4160f9cc26ee09"
      }
    ]
  ]
}'
```

Response

```
Failed to parse the request body: Unhandled error Invalid_argument("Hex.to_char: 111 is an invalid char")
```

For instance I was able to inject operation bytes and send it correctly:

```
async function sendTezos() {


// Instantiate a new TezosToolkit instance
  const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://02-dallas-051-01.rpc.tatum.io');

// Set the signer
  Tezos.setProvider({ signer: await InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey('edskRePSfPsrezMnp78MVZv4iWYNTK5qeZuUVqFLZiDC8yCzDLpWesmMhzddG4LLfvx3UHKpLL8WCbLv8RX1R7CjBpjDzYxDS7') });

// Create and inject the operation
  const op = await Tezos.contract.transfer({
    to: 'tz1Rwf9HHTrCEMjE5CwYdfTF3yYvuw6ip11c',
    amount: 1  // amount is in tez
  });

  console.log(op.raw.opOb.contents)

  console.log(op)

// Await confirmation
//   await op.confirmation();

}

sendTezos()
```

```
curl --location 'https://02-dallas-051-01.rpc.tatum.io/injection/operation' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxx' \
--data '"ddb22ca775467f08ba3288d53a141907d2f26c475f29e06032450749d50f35c86b00452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0f602adcdaf0acc0800007ff2737a3f5ed94332c4c44502133487ffcf6b27c1649713adff55345988a7486c00452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0f802aecdaf0ac90100c0843d0000452640fe2fdda2ca92b3c2207a740a7909f751c0000c0e091e8d9c8bf0a3747538a03c0b1da5d77d19f7b14ffb6b7a000bf5c368f03c14f5259b4375def0bd5450e55ddbabdca9f645411dbd7dda4160f9cc26ee09"'
```